# ¿Como pasar un string de C# (aspx.cs) a un arreglo de javascript para google maps?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, array, google-maps

Tengo una variable estática en mi clase del webform, que son coordenadas para un mapa de Google

```
public static string Query = "19.475 -91.97500000 19.475 -91.98333333 19.4833333 -91.98333333 19.4833333 -92.01666666 19.5 -92.01666666 19.5 -92.025 19.5333333 -92.025 19.5333333 -91.99166666 19.5166667 -91.99166666 19.525 -91.98333333 19.5 -91.98333333 19.5 -91.97500000 19.475 -91.97500000";
```

En mi bloque de Javascript Necesito un arreglo así:

```
var cuadrado = [
          { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 },
          { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
          { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
          { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 }
           ];
```

En mi codigo de javascript mando a llamar esa variable estática

```
var coords = "<%=Query %>";
```

A mi var llamada coords le hago split para remplazar las los espacios por comas ",". y lo mando a imprimir en mi navegador (Google Chrome)

```
var myArray = coords.split(" ");
alert(myArray);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Metí las coordenadas en un arreglo para despues recorrer el arreglo y concatenar las palabras "lat: "latitu", lng: "longitud" "

```
for(var d=0; d<myArray.length; d++)
          {
              myArray[i] = +myArray[i]; 
          }
```

Recorro el arreglo y concateno las palabras

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
          {

              for(var j=0; j<myArray.length;j++)
              {

                  var triangleCoords=[
                 {lat: myArray[i], lng:myArray[j]},
                  ];
              }
          }
```

Y necesito formar un bloque así, pero no lo imprime el ciclo anidado, 
Ayuda por favor

```
var cuadrado = [
          { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 },
          { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
          { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
          { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 }
           ];
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas ciclos anidados, solo uno que recorra el arreglo de dos en dos

```js
var query = "19.475 -91.97500000 19.475 -91.98333333 19.4833333 -91.98333333 19.4833333 -92.01666666 19.5 -92.01666666 19.5 -92.025 19.5333333 -92.025 19.5333333 -91.99166666 19.5166667 -91.99166666 19.525 -91.98333333 19.5 -91.98333333 19.5 -91.97500000 19.475 -91.97500000";

var numeros = query.split(' ');
var cuadrado;

cuadrado= "[{lat:" + numeros[0] + ", lng:" + numeros[1] + "}";

for(var i=2; i<numeros.length; i+=2){
  
  cuadrado+= ",{lat:" + numeros[i] + ", lng:" + numeros[i+1] + "}";
}
cuadrado +="]";
console.log(cuadrado);
```

Comment: Lo solucioné de otra forma, y tu codigo era bueno lo unico es que al poner "[" ya es un formato tipo texto yo necesitaba un arreglo de JavaScript, muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)